# trying to figure out which code is better to write

Tags: javascript

beginner javascript programmer here, I was wondering which code is considered better to write:

the two ways I wrote are inside the code block,
if there is a better way to write this code please lmk.

```js
const mark = {
  fullName: "Mark Miller",
  mass: 78,
  height: 1.69,

  calcBMI: function () {
    return (this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2);
  },
};

const john = {
  fullName: "John Smith",
  mass: 92,
  height: 1.95,

  calcBMI: function () {
    return (this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2);
  },
};

// 1st WAY -------------------------------
const higherBMI =
  mark.calcBMI() > john.calcBMI()
    ? `${mark.fullName}'s BMI (${mark.calcBMI()}) is higher than ${
        john.fullName
      }'s (${john.calcBMI()})!`
    : `${john.fullName}'s BMI (${john.calcBMI()}) is higher than ${
        mark.fullName
      }'s (${mark.calcBMI()})!`;

console.log(higherBMI);

// 2nd WAY -----------------------
mark.calcBMI(); 
john.calcBMI();

if (mark.bmi > john.bmi) {
  console.log(
    `${mark.fullName}'s BMI (${mark.calcBMI()}) is higher than ${
      john.fullName
    }'s (${john.calcBMI()})!`
  );
} else {
  console.log(
    `${john.fullName}'s BMI (${john.calcBMI()}) is higher than ${
      mark.fullName
    }'s (${mark.calcBMI()})!`
  );
}
```

Comment: For questions like this, use [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Whichever code you think reads better is easier for you to understand is the better way to write code. Remember if you've written it, most likely you will have to read it again in the future. So, write it in a way that makes it easier for you to read in the future.

Comment: That said if we were working together. I'd prefer that you write it the 2nd way because its easier for me to read and understand at first glance what the code is doing. It may be a little more verbose but I understand it better.

Comment: Consider this option: instead of having `mark` and `john` objects, keep an array of `people` objects. This way you can sort the array and print the top 2. This also adds the ability to add more people.

Comment: You have the same function in two places. Your console logs are also the same. Try your best to follow the DRY principle. If in the future you had to refactor the function or console logs you'd have to do it in two places. If you add a third person, you'd have to repeat that function again. Separate the function from the object and move the console log into its own function. In fact, you can also club the console log and the BMI calc function because you will be passing the same parameters. Also, if you combine this comment with @JohnnyMopp you'd produce reusable code much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should calculate `BMI` only once and store the result instead of calculating it every time you need it, and `calcBMI()` shouldn't return anything

```
mark.calcBMI(); 
john.calcBMI();

if (mark.bmi > john.bmi) {
  console.log(
    `${mark.fullName}'s BMI (${mark.bmi}) is higher than ${
      john.fullName
    }'s (${john.bmi})!`
  );
} else {
  console.log(
    `${john.fullName}'s BMI (${john.bmi}) is higher than ${
      mark.fullName
    }'s (${mark.bmi})!`
  );
}
```

Other valid solution is

```
mark.calcBMI(); 
john.calcBMI();

const higher = mark.bmi > john.bmi ? mark : john;
const lower = mark.bmi > john.bmi ? mark : john;
console.log(
  `${higher.fullName}'s BMI (${higher.bmi}) is higher than ${lower.fullName}'s (${lower.bmi})!`
);
```

PS: your assume that both bmi values are different